# How to combine 2 of this id in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

My code :

```
$this->db->where("followers.id_follower",$id_user); 
$this->db->where("users.id_following",$id_user);
```

my models : http://pastebin.com/5ipyj6iA

[image]

Comment: Your problem is not clear. If you want to display only one column as in image, just select any one either `followers.id_follower` or `users.id_following` neither `id_following` nor both column, your given code looks ok.

Comment: do you want to combine where condition or something else please explain

Comment: get a photo of followers and her own picture

Comment: You should paste code in your question rather than use pastebain

Answer (score 0):

you can try this where clause for your problem :

```
$where = "followers.id_follower=$id_user AND users.id_following= $id_user";
$this->db->where($where);
```